# Can you please help me with this optics problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection, geometric-optics

Question:

A person standing in front of a mirror finds his image thinner but with normal height. this implies that the mirror is

```
a) convex and spherical

b) concave and spherical

c) Convex and cylindrical with the axis 
vertical

d) Convex and cylindrical with the axis 
horizontal
```

I am confused how can any mirror form an image which is thinner than the object, because as far as I know concave, convex and plain mirror can form images of different sizes (but not of different width) either virtual or real. Please help me out.

The correct option is (a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct. because of the reason that you explained the answer must be c.

The mirror cannot be spherical because the image is changed in one direction more than the other. It has to be cylindrical with vertical axis to allow distortion horizontally and not vertically.

It has to be convex because it is thinner.

Thus it has to be "Convex and cylindrical with axis vertical"